# Flutter: facebook signed in user is not showing in firebase console

Tags: facebook, firebase, flutter

I am using facebook sign in flutter, everything is working fine but the firebase console is not showing the facebook signed in user.

I have implemented according to the changelog as shown in the firebase_auth [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) and flutter_facebook_login [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login#-changelog-tab-).

Code for login functionality

```
Future<FirebaseUser> facebookLogin(BuildContext context) async {
    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    // fbLogin.loginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.webViewOnly;
    // if you remove above comment then facebook login will take username and pasword for login in Webview
    try {
      final FacebookLoginResult facebookLoginResult =
      await fbLogin.logIn(['email']);
      if (facebookLoginResult.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
        FacebookAccessToken facebookAccessToken =
            facebookLoginResult.accessToken;
        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(
            accessToken: facebookAccessToken.token);
        FirebaseUser user = (await auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
        print("signed in"+ user.displayName);
      return user;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return currentUser;
  }
```

Button from where functionality is called

```
onTap: (){
                          facebookLogin(context).then((user) {
                            if (user != null) {
                              print('Logged in successfully.');
                              setState(() {
                                isFacebookLoginIn = true;
                                successMessage =
                                'Logged in successfully.\nEmail : ${user.email}\nYou can now navigate to Home Page.';
                              });
                            } else {
                              print('Error while Login.');
                            }
                          });
```

My flutter output console

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 5A in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
I/flutter (15427): Logged in successfully.
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Syncing files to device Redmi 5A...
I/flutter (17353): signed inAtul Chaudhary
I/flutter (17353): Logged in successfully.
```

As you can see the User Is correctly signed in using facebook.

Here is the photo of my firebase console[image: firebase Console]

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, Do you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you're receiving the accessToken if you do, then make sure you're following the below steps:

`final firebaseAuthCred = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token);`

then

`final result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCred);`

now check Firebase Console and you might be able to find your registered user.